# Passing an array to a function in c

Tags: c, arrays, scope

I have a doubt regarding passing of arrays to a function.

consider the following code snippet.

```
void main()
{
    int a[4]={10,20,30,40};
    fun1(a);
}

void fun1(int a1[])
{
  for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
  {
      printf("%d\n",a1[i]);
  }
}
```

Passing an array is nothing but passing the address of the first location.
And I should pass the above array with its name(starting address of the array).
My doubt is since a[4] is an auto variable, it should die when it comes out of the main function and it should give the unexpected results(the pointer should be dangled).
But it is working fine.

I am very confused with this, can you please clear it off.

Even if we pass a single element `int a` as `f(&a)`, it should not exist in the function f, if it is declared as automatic(local variable in main function).

Please clear this as well.

Comment: If any answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, variable `a` will be out of scope when `main()` terminates.

But when `fun1` is executing, `main()` has not reached termination yet, so the content of `a` is still perfectly valid.

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing is fine. The array `a` does indeed go out of scope but by that point your function has finished so you don't have to worry about accessing data that is no longer around. If you have concerns about passing the variable as the array name (which is fine) you can always step through your code to ensure you are accessing the data you think that you are.

You could also make your function safer by passing an additional integer argument that specifies the size of your array rather than having it hard coded as 4. If you used the function you have and passed an integer array of length less than 4, it will be accessing out of bounds memory.

Answer (score 1):

1. void fun1 ( int a1[]) is creating a copy of whatever array is coming into the function. So it will exist.
2. You can also vision it as a stack. A stack will be created for main() method. And since the fun1() is called from the main method, the stack of main method will destroy only when the stack for fun1() is destroyed.

Comment: `fun1` does *not* create a copy of the array; it only creates a copy of a pointer to the first element.

Answer (score 0):

`int a[]` in function declaration/definition is equal to `const int *a` so nothing bad will happen and no memory will be freed implicitly.